# Get GameObject last and current transform.position from script

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to be able to know the following positions when animating an object:

```
Last Frame transform.position
Current transform.position
```

i know how can i get the `current transform.position` just by asking `transform.position` in the `LateUpdate(){}` callback.
but how can i get the last frame position?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just store current transform.position so that when the next Update is called you can read and use this variable which will be last frame transform.position?

Comment: @Unai i am thinking about it...

Comment: There is no need to think - that is literally the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic structure behind it:

```
class PositionUpdaterThing
{
    Vector3 _lastPosition;

    void Update() 
    {
        // get current position
        currentPosition = transform.position;

        // do anything you need to with the positions
        DoStuff(currentPosition, _lastPosition);

        // set last to current so the next frame of Update() is ready
        _lastPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // set initial value for lastPosition
        _lastPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```